# one-to-many relationship MYSQL database `ERROR 1061: Duplicate key name`

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys

I have made tables in a DB and am trying to make foreign keys in the tables and got this error.

I was expecting that I can make a one-to-many relationship for the tables but did not make a connection.

```
Error : ERROR 1061: Duplicate key name 'emp_id_idx'
SQL Statement:
ALTER TABLE `hrmsemployee`.`leavetable` 
ADD INDEX `emp_id_idx` (`emp_id` ASC) VISIBLE
```

Comment: Index names must be unique within a given table. The error "duplicate key name" indicates that you must already have created the index. Run the SQL command `SHOW CREATE TABLE hrmsemployee.leavetable` in a MySQL client to check what indexes currently exist in the table.

Comment: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.